# Why was "opinion based" flag declined, when even the author of the question agrees it's opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/should-a-student-pilot-use-their-license-to-go-somewhere) as "primarily opinion-based".

The language in the question makes very clear that the author is asking for an opinion. *"Should"* is the word they use, rather than something like *"is it legal?"*

In a comment, [the author of the question wrote](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/should-a-student-pilot-use-their-license-to-go-somewhere#comment234582_88201):

> …my question is more opinion based. I’m fairly positive there is no regulation against it.

All evidence points to the question being opinion-based, and yet the moderator handling the flag disagreed.

I would appreciate understanding on what basis that moderator decided that the question was not in fact "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the community voted to keep the question open in the [review queue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/58552) initiated by your flag.

Since the community disagreed with the flag, the system has automatically declined the flag.

Comment: Ah...I see. I was under the impression that review queue dispositions would only result in "disputed" at worst. Thanks for clearing that up. (Why the community has such a hard time understanding what's opinion-based and what's not is a whole other issue, but neither here nor there.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I can ask around in the next days, but I have the feeling that "disputed" happens only if at least one reviewer agrees with the flag.

Comment: Up until the OP posted his "yeah I'm looking for opinions" comment, which happened after the "close as opinion-based" flag was voted down in the review queue, I think reviewers read the text of the question with a presumption toward validity - i.e. that the ambiguity in the question should be resolved in favor of it being on-topic. "Is this plan legal" would be a valid question, so I (and apparently others) assumed that's what the OP was asking. Once he cleared up that he knew the answer to that & was asking for opinions, the "close" flag was already dead. At this point, tho, I'd VTC it.